# What is the memmove_overlay command in AIX?

Tags: c, unix, aix

I'm debugging a dynamic memory allocation problem in some C code in AIX 6.1 and in my stack trace I get the command memmove_overlay before the crash.

Before the program crashed I had called the memcpy function.

What is this command doing ?

Comment: Please show some code.  However, I think Ryan is correct.

Comment: It is hard to figure everything out from the scarce info you provided, but guessing by the names, you probably called `memcpy` for overlapping memory regions. It is illegal to call `memcpy` for overlapping memory regions. The rest follows.

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` copies a memory area from *src to *dest.  It might crash your program if the memory areas overlap.  Try `memmove` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Verify the parameters to your `memmove()` call. The internal-sounding `memmove_overlay()` function is part of the implementation of `memmove()`, so it's doing the same thing as `memmove()` is doing, probably.

You could of course set up a dummy test case using a known safe set of parameters, like so:

```
char test1[2], test2[2] = { 47, 11 };

memmove(test2, test1, sizeof test2);
```

And then use your debugger to step into `memmove()` to see how it ends up in `memmove_overlay()`.

But, chances are that the crash just is because of bad input to `memmove()`, and thus has nothing to do with the fact that the `memmove_overlay()` function is running.